# Schedule Executor's Schedule Method is Executing Only Once

Tags: android, scheduledexecutorservice

I am trying to implement a sample schedule where I want the toast to be displayed every 10 seconds.But the schedule method is running only once.Is there any solution.
Here is my code

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService= Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    scheduledExecutorService.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello Schedule", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    },
    10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation on the difference between `ScheduledExecutorService#schedule()` and `ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleAt*`

Comment: Please can you suggest the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking for **scheduleAtFixedRate** method.

> **scheduleAtFixedRate :**
>   Creates and executes a periodic action that becomes enabled first
>   after the given initial delay, and subsequently with the given period;
>   that is, executions will commence after initialDelay, then
>   initialDelay + period, then initialDelay + 2 * period, and so on.
>   [Documentaion](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

**Example**

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService;
    scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello Schedule",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }},2,10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```